# For what its used dyntopo and why this artist did two sculptings (dyntopo and multiresolution sculpting)?

Tags: sculpting

i want to know why this incredible artist used two ways to sculpt and what its the diference of them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc3cRVG3me4 that i know multiresolution its needed for sculpting, i though before that subsurface subdivision does the same work but isnt the same modifier. by the way i also need a link of more good sculpting brushes for blender 2.78a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multires sculpting is more traditional for a production (e.g. cinema) pipeline because it uses quads (much safer & easier to work with). Multires is superior to SubSurf modifier for sculpting because Multires stores topography data at each tier, whereas Subsurf discards data when subdivision value is decreased.

Multires is much less efficient because every single face is being subdivided (2 > 4 > 8 > 16 ect) across the entire mesh. Poly count gets out of hand VERY quickly.

DYNATOPO is a technology originally created (I think?) by Pixologic for Zbrush, integrated with Blender 3-4 years ago as I recall. While in sculpt mode, enabling Dynatopo TRIANGULATES your mesh (divides 4-vertex faces into 3-vertex faces by splitting them in half). Tri's are capable of MANIFOLD subdivision, meaning some areas can be more detail-dense than others, thereby allowing you to create detail in areas that need it while leaving flat areas with a relatively low poly count. Changing your mesh from QUADS to TRIS is destructive, and often requires retopology (painstakingly rebuilding the mesh with a tool like [RetopoFlow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow)).

So there's your answer. I won't give you a link to good sculpting brushes—you'll have to do your own footwork, but Jim (James) Morren is an expert on the subject. Look for what tools he's created or recommended.